# Google App Engine, Python, deleting a cookie or changing its value?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, cookies, header

I've been searching on this but can't seem to figure out how I can delete a specific cookie using Google Apps Engine, Python version. I am setting the cookie like below and I need to update its value, I figure I may not be able to update and just need to delete and re-create but can't seem to find the way to do that, I am creating it as below:

```
        str = 'if_loggedin_username='+ self.username
        self.from_obj.response.headers.add_header(
                                 'Set-Cookie', str)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way for the server to delete an HTTP cookie.  To update the value, just send a new cookie with the same name and it will be updated; to "delete" the cookie, set an expiration time in the past.

Comment: hmmm.. well I tried that--just setting a new cookie and it seemed to create another one with the same name, so there were 2 of them. I will test again if see if it just was a fluke, so it should just update it instead of creating another one?

Comment: nevermind, I had been setting a different path for the 2nd one which is why it was giving 2... thanks for the help, this clears the issue up for me

Comment: It should be impossible for a browser to store 2 cookies with the same name for the same domain.  A browser that allows this isn't compliant with RFC 2109.

Comment: well its storing the same name but different path, I'm using latest ver of firefox

Comment: Doesn't `delete_cookie` work? http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more, send a new cookie with same name with value None (NoneType)

```
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", None)
```

Hope it helps